# How do you say "question", and which counter should be used?

Tags: word-choice, counters, questions

I'd like to know the word for "question" itself. For example if I wanted to say:

> I have a question
>
> わたしは (question) があります。

I've had a hard time finding an answer to this question because when I search, Google turns up results for question words instead, and I'd rather ask a fluent speaker than a dictionary.

I'd also like to know what counter should be used for counting questions, and if it is regular (so if, when pronouncing the number before the counter it just follows the regular sequence of いち, に, さん, し etc. or if there are any exceptions.)

Apologies for asking three questions, I can move them onto separate threads if need be, but they're all related which is why I didn't.

Comment: [Euphonic changes with counters](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_counter_word#Euphonic_changes)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

しつもん（質問） means question, so the sentence would be わたしは　しつもんが　あります。
Interestingly the counter for question is もん（問） which is the last syllable of しつもん [source](http://www.romajidesu.com/dictionary/meaning-of-%E5%95%8F.html)。

I don't know how to say you have three questions, as you can probably tell I'm not a native speaker, but I think you can say I have some questions, using いくつか（幾つか） which means some, a few or several [source](http://www.romajidesu.com/dictionary/meaning-of-%E5%B9%BE%E3%81%A4%E3%81%8B.html). So the sentence would be like this わたしは幾つかの質問があります or わたしは質問がいくつかあります。

Comment: That should be `わたしは質問がいくつかあります` or `わたしはいくつかの質問があります`.  Similarly, you could replace `いくつか` with however many you have (`一つ`, `二つ`, etc.).

Comment: Thanks @istrasci I edited the answer, could you explain why you need the の particle?

Comment: @Olumide, why did you edit "幾つか質問があります" to "幾つか*の*質問があります"?  いくつか/一つ質問があります (without の) sounds more natural than いくつか*の*/一つ*の*質問があります.

Comment: @Chocolate: I would have made the same comment as Istrasci because counters and nouns are usually connected by の. Does anybody have a simple reason why it is more natural without の　here? It might be worth question by itself.

Comment: @Tim I made the same mistake (though I deleted my comment to cover it up! :-)  My guess is that it's because counter words, although they're considered nouns, can also function like adverbs, and adverbs don't need particles.  So it would be the same reason that you don't need a particle when you write `質問が一つあります`.

Comment: @snailplane: I guess that must be the case. Thanks.

Comment: @Chocolate because of what istrasci said, so I thought I was wrong.

Comment: @istrasci - I know very few kanji besides the numbers, does `質問` = `しつもん`? Also, why `一つ`, `二つ`, `三つ` (I'm presuming you mean `ひとつ`, `ふたつ`, `みっつ` etc.?) Isn't the counter `もん` as Olumide said?

Comment: And just to make sure I've understood: "I have three questions" = `わたしは三もんがあります`。 いいですか。

Comment: Yes, `質問` = `しつもん` (Olumide put it in their answer).  `もん` may be the actual counter, but sounds too formal in conversation (to me).  You'd use that to say like "This test has 20 questions" or something.

Comment: So it doesn't seem lazy to use `ひとつ`, `ふたつ`, `みっつ` etc. in this context?

Comment: I've accepted, although not all the information was in the post, but the comments on here in addition have answered my questions.